# Node js on apache2 failed

Tags: node.js, apache2, systemctl

I am trying to setup a node server on a apache...maybe thats a dumb idea idk.

When I try to start my node-project.service I get the following error.

node-project.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Node.js Application
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/node_project
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /var/www/html/node_prject/index.js



[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Error:

```
× node-project.service - Node.js Application
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/node-project.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-03-20 19:06:01 UTC; 6s ago
    Process: 2593 ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /var/www/html/node_prject/index.js (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2593 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 109ms

Mar 20 19:06:01 inventory node[2593]:     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1134>
Mar 20 19:06:01 inventory node[2593]:     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:27)
Mar 20 19:06:01 inventory node[2593]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/mod>
Mar 20 19:06:01 inventory node[2593]:     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
Mar 20 19:06:01 inventory node[2593]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Mar 20 19:06:01 inventory node[2593]:   requireStack: []
Mar 20 19:06:01 inventory node[2593]: }
Mar 20 19:06:01 inventory node[2593]: Node.js v18.19.1
Mar 20 19:06:01 inventory systemd[1]: node-project.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAIL>
Mar 20 19:06:01 inventory systemd[1]: node-project.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
~
```

I followed some some guides on setting this up and some post here on SO but I cant seem to get the node server to run